# Dialogflow CX Generator Fulfillment doesn't use Data Store created with Vertex AI Search to answer questions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, dialogflow-cx

I'm building a Q&A Support chatbot (in Spanish) based in GCP for a specific platform, making use of Vertex AI Search to analyze the PDF files that contain the documentation for said platform. Dialogflow CX then takes said documentation and uses a Generator to generate the fulfillment with said Data Store.

Generator prompt (I've tried writing the prompt in Spanish and making it more restrictive with what it can use)

[image: Generator prompt (I've tried writing the prompt in Spanish and making it more restrictive with what it can use)]

[image: Agent response]

The problem is that, whenever I ask a question, Dialogflow Messenger returns two things: the generated response and the reference from the Data Store. The reference from the Data Store is correct (that is, it supposedly analyzes the document correctly and knows where to look for the answer) but the generated response is completely made up (I assume the model searches the prompt in Google for an answer instead of the Data Store, despite me having specified in the prompt to only use the Data Store)

[image: Query and response]

In the picture above, I ask a basic question that is explicitly answered in the documentation, and the second response, which is the reference, is correct, but the generated response doesn't even apply to the context. I've asked several questions that were both explicitly asked (As in I write the same exact string of text that is already in the document) and could be answered from inference, and none have worked correctly so far.

I have tried adjusting the parameters of the generator, changing the prompt to be more restrictive with the use of the data store and creating the chatbot in English, but none of these things work.

Comment: 1. Did you check that the response object in the test agent has a generator-related response?

2. Problems may occur with training of data sources. For example, the quality of PDF can affect training.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$request.knowledge.answer` use `$request.knowledge.answer[0]`.